# Retrofit 2 Issue<Using Custom GSON Converters for multiple Base_API_URLs>

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

I have searched extensively on SO and issues list here but could not find an optimal solution to the issue (This came close however: [RETROFIT how to parse this response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34421851/retrofit-how-to-parse-this-response/34421880).).

Can someone help me out? Here is the gist:
https://gist.github.com/Sheshlok/f8ee09a6760f6aa3b05ad9c03d6b247b

**Issue**: The second API returns a malformed JSON response, specifically, one that is wrapped in `finance_charts_json_callback(.....)`. I tried implementing a custom `GSON` converter as you can see in the gist above but keep getting the same error

```
([@Observable#getStockHistory -> onError() -> 'Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 1 path $'])
```

**Note**:

1. Have checked JsonpParser with the actual API response and it works fine.
2. I can solve this problem by using OkHttp class 'onResponse'
   callback, and trimming the response string appropriately before
   parsing JSON. However, I needed to use Observables.